# How to deploy Branding Artifacts to SharePoint 2013 Online Publishing Site?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365

What is the recommended way to deploy branding artifacts (Master Pages/Page Layouts) to SharePoint 2013 Online (Publishing Site)?

Tried packaging them into a Sandbox solution, but "Solutions" gallery is missing in "Site Settings" of the publishing site.

Answer (score -1):

May by you can use this solution?

[A guide to quick SharePoint 2013 branding](http://blog.blksthl.com/2013/02/26/a-guide-to-quick-sharepoint-2013-branding/)